# Update an item in the list

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm a beginner on knockout.

I made this page:

http://jsfiddle.net/LhTx4/

I would like to update only the item that comes back from the sellIt function.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the `quantity` property incorrectly. `quantity` is a `ko observable` so you need to use the syntax:

```
        self.sellIt = function (product) {
            $.post('/Product/SellIt', { id: product.id },
            function (data) {
                var res = Enumerable.From(self.products)
                            .Where("i => i.id == " + data.Id)
                            .Select("s => s");

                res.quantity(data.Quantity); // this is the important bit!!
            });
        };
```

However, I think you could probably shorten your code down to just:

```
        self.sellIt = function (product) {
            $.post('/Product/SellIt', { id: product.id },
            function (data) {
                product.quantity(data.Quantity);
            });
        };
```